# Why are the following determinant the same?

Tags: matrices

I search on the internet but get no answers, could anybody help me please?

I mean which rule does it use?

[image]

Comment: Add the last two columns to the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can swap one column (or line) by any linear combination of columns (or lines) without changing the determinant. Do the operation: $$L_1 := L_1 + L_2 + L_3$$

Comment: Multiplying out two $3\times 3$ determinants and comparing the two resulting cubics wouldn't be that much harder...

Comment: @User58220 Yes, it wouldn't. But why bother, if we know the theory? (: